# Vite React app: esbuild error in Docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, vite

I'm trying to get to grips with both vite and docker so I apologise if I've made stupid mistakes.

I'm running into an issue with esbuild inside docker. I'm trying to get a dev setup going, so I want to mount my code in my containers so that changes should be reflected in real time.

Previously I used Dockerfiles which copied `/frontend` and `/backend` into their respective containers and that worked, I had my `web` and `api` containers running and happily talking to each other. However, it meant it didn't pick up any code changes so it wasn't suitable for development.

So I've switched to volume mounts in the hope that I can get my dockerized apps to hot reload, but hit this error instead.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    image: node:16-slim
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - ./shared:/shared
    working_dir: /app
    command: yarn start:dev
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
  web:
    image: node:16-slim
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - ./shared:/shared
    working_dir: /app
    command: yarn dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

here's my vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 3000,
    fs: {
      strict: false,
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

[image: docker-compose up -d --build]

So this is the error that I'm trying to fix:

```
web_1  | yarn run v1.22.15
web_1  | $ vite
web_1  | failed to load config from /app/vite.config.js
web_1  | error when starting dev server:
web_1  | Error: The package "esbuild-linux-64" could not be found, and is needed by esbuild.
web_1  |
web_1  | If you are installing esbuild with npm, make sure that you don't specify the
web_1  | "--no-optional" flag. The "optionalDependencies" package.json feature is used
web_1  | by esbuild to install the correct binary executable for your current platform.
web_1  |     at generateBinPath (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1643:15)
web_1  |     at esbuildCommandAndArgs (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1699:11)
web_1  |     at ensureServiceIsRunning (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1856:25)
web_1  |     at Object.build (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1749:26)
web_1  |     at bundleConfigFile (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-713b45e1.js:68592:34)
web_1  |     at loadConfigFromFile (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-713b45e1.js:68569:35)
web_1  |     at resolveConfig (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-713b45e1.js:68119:34)
web_1  |     at createServer (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-713b45e1.js:66633:26)
web_1  |     at CAC.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:687:30)
web_1  | error Command failed with exit code 1.
web_1  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
homepage_web_1 exited with code 1
```

I've spent most of the day reading various similar SO questions and github threads but nothing I found specifically addresses this, at least in a way I understand. I'd be really grateful if anyone could either point out where I've gone wrong, or point me at an example of a dockerized vite/react app with good dev and prod setups. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally managed to get this working having read and better understood this discussion; https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2671#issuecomment-829535806.

I'm on MacOS but the container is running Linux and the architecture is mismatched when it attempts to use the version of esbuild from my mounted volume. So, I need to rebuild esbuild inside the container. I tried to use the entrypoint script as that thread suggests but that didn't work for me.

What did work was to change the command in my `docker-compose.yml` to `command: sh -c "npm rebuild esbuild && yarn dev"`.

It's now hot reloading like a dream.

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I ran Vite on an older version of Node Js. When Node and Npm were updated - the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where esbuild needed `@esbuild/linux-64` for build, the error was `The package "@esbuild/linux-x64" could not be found, and is needed by esbuild` but my MacOS environment prevents me from installing it via `npm i @esbuild/linux-64`.

I was able to fix this problem by adding it to the optional dependencies in my `package.json`, this [type of dependency](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#optionalDependencies) looks available too with Yarn.

```json
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@esbuild/linux-x64": "^0.20.1"
  }
```